# Subtract DateTime intervals in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I have first table with defined work times: `FreeTimes table (start datetime, end datetime)` and second table with already planned tasks: `TaskTime table (start datetime, end datetime)`.

I need somehow to subtract second table from first, so i get a result set of remainig FreeTimes under this conditions:

- in case where TaskTime (or more TaskTimes) is in middle of FreeTime, i need to split FreeTime to time before task and time ramaining after task
- in case when TaskTime is overlapping entire FreeTime i need to filter out this FreeTime
- in case where TaskTime is intersecting with FreeTime i need to subtract TaskTime from FreeTime and leave only remaing part of FreeTime

Comment: Presumably, more complex situations are also possible (e.g. a FreeTime overlapped by multiple TaskTimes...)

Comment: Cann't you just find DATEDIFF(minute,FreeTimes.start,FreeTimes.end) - DATEDIFF(minute,TaskTime.start, TaskTime.end) ? And then you can group by whatever required columns to find it for the day or for employee, for specific day.

Comment: @010001100110000101110010011010 i need as resultset records of intervals with start and end DateTime, not only sum of free minutes in day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general way I'd solve this is as follows:

```
;With AllTimes as (
    select [Start] as EventTime from FreeTimes
    union
    select [End] from FreeTimes
    union
    select [Start] from TaskTimes
    union
    select [End] from TaskTimes
), OrderedTimes as (
    select EventTime,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EventTime) rn
    from AllTimes
), Intervals as (
    select
        ot1.EventTime as StartTime,
        ot2.EventTime as EndTime
    from
        OrderedTimes ot1
            inner join
        OrderedTimes ot2
            on
                ot1.rn = ot2.rn - 1
)
select * from Intervals i
where not exists (
    select * from TaskTimes T where --Overlapped
       T.[Start] < i.EndTime and
       T.[End] > i.StartTime)
and exists (
    select * from FreeTimes T where
       T.[Start] < i.EndTime and
       T.[End] > i.StartTime)
```

Where we basically order all datetime values of interest, and then for each pair of successive values, work out if there's some overlap with the `TaskTimes` table. If there is, then that pair shouldn't be in the final result. (**edit** - we also have to check that the interval pair does actually overlap with `FreeTimes` too)

You can, if needed, take this further and merge intervals (if there are overlapping rows in `FreeTimes`, you may end up with multiple intervals which are adjacent to each other)

Comment: Looks good, but this also return gaps between FreeTimes, eg. when freetimes is entire Monday and Wednesday, this return Thuesday(gap) in result

Comment: @fanosek - I knew I was missing something. You can add a second `exists` check to the last query. I'll edit that in.